# Error in Posting Tweets using twitter api

Tags: c#, twitter

I tried to post a tweet using twitter api via c#.
i have app key and appscecrt with app permission as read and write.
i am bale to get access token also.
But not bale to post the tweet or update  status
But im getting forbidden error exception every time. can anyone help me with this.

```
    public class TwitAuthenticateResponse
    {
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
    }
    class twitterSupporter{       
        public void postTweets()
        {                  
          try
            {
                // api for posting tweets
              var timelineFormat = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";

                HttpWebRequest timeLineRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(timelineFormat);
                var timelineHeaderFormat = "{0} {1}";
                timeLineRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format(timelineHeaderFormat, twitAuthResponse.token_type, twitAuthResponse.access_token));
                timeLineRequest.Method = "Post";
                var timeLineJson = string.Empty;
                var status = "its done";
                using (Stream stream = timeLineRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(status);
                    stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
                }


                WebResponse timeLineResponse = timeLineRequest.GetResponse();

                using (timeLineResponse)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(timeLineResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        timeLineJson = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    }
                }

            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                //handle web exception
            }
    }
```

Comment: The only reason you are receiving forbidden response is because one of your credentials is not correct. Review all the details and make sure you are a registered user in twitter as well, as you have to be a registered and well known client in order to use the api.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have an Authorization header, but a simple string.Format with plugged-in values seems unlikely to help. The OAuth standard calls for a specifically processed string, described here for Twitter:

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures

Here's how I build that authorization string in LINQ to Twitter:

https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/blob/master/src/LinqToTwitter/LinqToTwitter.Shared/Security/OAuth.cs

Additionally, the OAuth process is fraught with pitfalls along the way, so I've collected a list of items that might help in a FAQ:

https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/LINQ-to-Twitter-FAQ